# Laravel Authentication not remain

Tags: php, laravel, api, session, authentication

I created an API to login in my web app. After checking the parameters, use the Auth method: loginUsingId() with the id of the user to be logged in.
After that I get authenticated correctly, in fact doing an echo Auth::user() shows the user property correctly.
However, by making a redirect to another project page, I am no longer logged in the portal and shows me the login page.
It seems that the user's session does not remain or that is not created at all.
I use Laravel 5.6. I have no middleware for the route.

Comment: Have you used the middleware for that page, which you are accessing?

Comment: API is not the same as browser, so you will need an access token to be sent each time you make a request for the same user. 
Look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? Can you share the routes file and the middleware codes related to that route you're redirecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time your page accesses the API, it's essentially talking to a brand new instance of the API.

Think of it like this.  Your "login" endpoint is not actually telling the API to log someone in.  It's telling it to merely verify the caller's claim that the given password belongs to the given user, end of story.  If you want to turn that authentication into actual "login" behavior from the UI perspective, there's other steps you need to take.

If Laravel is serving up Blade files for your site, then it's a different story.  Out-of-the-box, it generates a Php session for you, and sends the session-key cookie to the browser for use in subsequent requests.

Similar to a session-key, for maintaining a session between a website and a separate API, you need each subsequent call to include a token.  And you need the login endpoint to provide that token upon successful authentication.

Passport is one way to go, but it might be overkill for your situation.  Passport is good for handling users, clients, and authorization permissions.  But if all you want is authentication and you're not as concerned with controlling what they have access to beyond that, then I highly recommend [Tymon JWT-Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

Both Passport and JWT-Auth use "bearer tokens" in the 'Authorization' header.  There're other kinds though, like "basic tokens".  A basic token is just an encoded concatenation of the username and password.  [Laravel supports this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#http-basic-authentication) with a route middleware, but I do still recommend going with JWT.

One of the nice things about JWT is you can actually include extraneous data within the token itself.  And it positions you better to lean into Passport (OAuth2) if/when you need it, by not requiring your client-side to change its authentication method.